# Evaluate 2 conditional expressions in a th:if or th:unless

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

My code is like that:

```
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
      <h1 class="page-header" th:utext="#{dashboard}">Dashboard</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main" th:if="${lista}">
      <h1 class="page-header" th:text="#{__${name}__}"></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main" th:if="${command}">
      <h1 class="page-header"><th:block th:utext="#{__${action}__}"/> <th:block th:utext="#{__${name}__}"/></h1>
    </div>
```

the second `<div>` block is displayed if `lista` is not null. the third is displayed when `command` is not null. the first one should be displayed when both `lista` and `command` are null. something like that:

```
${lista} && ${command}
```

but this expression causes an error. anyone knows how to do that?

**UPDATE**

I try: `${lista && command}` and `${lista and command}` but do not solve my problem (still happenning an error).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have multiple condition in an th:if tag using thymeleaf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018577/how-to-have-multiple-condition-in-an-thif-tag-using-thymeleaf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @Andrew referenced to the right link.
If you need to check `lista` is null and `command` is null just check it.
I'm not sure, but this syntax is incorrect I guess - `th:if="${lista}"`.
Use `th:if="${lista != null}"` instead.

So, for checking both conditions :

```
th:if="${lista == null and command == null}"
```